# Select counted rows and count in the same query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, row

Table Items

```
(code, id, value)
1      2    value1
1      3    value2
1      4    value4
1      5    value5
2      2    valueX
2      3    valueY
2      4    valueZ
```

Result may be:

```
(code, id, value, count)
1      2    value1     4
1      3    value2     4
1      4    value4     4
1      5    value5     4
2      2    valueX     3
2      3    valueY     3
2      4    valueZ     3
```

But the problem is when I use COUNT(code) I get:

```
1      2    value1     4
2      2    valueX     2
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you extract data using from mysql using language for example, PHP, you get rows numbers besides data.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to determine the RecordCount for each code, and `INNER JOIN` that into the original query, to provide the extra column.  *IF* you are using PHP, it may be more efficient though to listen to the comment user366534 had about determining this count once you get into the client code.

```
SELECT i.code, i,id, i.value, s.RecordCount
FROM items AS i
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT it.Code, COUNT(1) AS RecordCount
   FROM items AS it
   GROUP BY it.Code
) AS s ON i.code = s.code
```